# Django. Doesn't pass foreign key to the template

Tags: python, django, django-views

In Django I filtered the data and displayed the result like. for example

```
Alabama(20)
Iowa(12)
```

Here "*Alabama,Iowa*" are State Names and inside the brackets "20,12" are no. of jobs available by the particular States. While click the Alabama or Iowa it displays job openings available in that particular state. But I doesn't pass emp_id to template page. Give some idea to this...

*models.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
     first_name= forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     username = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())
     email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput())
     password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
     companyname = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput())

class jobs(models.Model):
     emp = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     referencecode = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     jobsummary = models.TextField()
     jobdetails = models.TextField()
     key_skills = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     states = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

*views.py*

```
def search_result(request):
     details3 = jobs.objects.values('state').annotate(count=Count('state')).order_by('-count')
     return render_to_response('searchresult.html', {'details3': details3})
```

*searchresult.html*

```
{% for d2 in details3 %}
<li><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="/accounts/CompanyList/{{d2.emp}}/" >{{ d2.state}}({{ d2.count }})</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jobs.objects.values('state')
```

You only select `state` field, why do you expect `emp` to be there as well?

```
jobs.objects.values('state', 'emp_id')
```

Is this is what you wanted?